# how to catch the exception for "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

Tags: c#

I m getting "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden." error and want to catch this exception. I guess HttpException block should trap it as shown below but its not.

```
catch (HttpException wex)
       {
       if (wex.GetHttpCode().ToString() == "403")
       //do stuff
       }
```

I don't want to use generic exception block to catch this. What other exception could catch this?

See the attached the exception snapshotscreenshot.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [HttpWebResponse returns 404 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857512/httpwebresponse-returns-404-error)

Comment: Indeed it should catch the exception (if an `HttpException` is being thrown -- maybe it's a `WebException` instead), though I don't know why you are calling `.ToString()` here when you could just test `wex.GetHttpCode() == 403`.

Comment: Find out for yourself: break the debugger and find out the type of the exception, or use a temporary `catch (Exception exception)` and `Console.WriteLine(exception.GetType().Name)`

Comment: @cdhowie gave you the right answer here, it's a WebException.

Comment: I have also tried to catch through this block and it does not work either (System.Net.WebException wex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the exception is being wrapped inside of another API-level exception object.  You can conditionally catch the specific exception you are after and re-throw otherwise.  Using this helper:

```
static T GetNestedException<T>(Exception ex) where T : Exception
{
    if (ex == null) { return null; }

    var tEx = ex as T;
    if (tEx != null) { return tEx; }

    return GetNestedException<T>(ex.InnerException);
}
```

You can then use this catch block:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var wex = GetNestedException<WebException>(ex);

    // If there is no nested WebException, re-throw the exception.
    if (wex == null) { throw; }

    // Get the response object.
    var response = wex.Response as HttpWebResponse;

    // If it's not an HTTP response or is not error 403, re-throw.
    if (response == null || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Forbidden) {
        throw;
    }

    // The error is 403.  Handle it here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the stacktrace without you catching it. If the code doesn't allow you to not catch it, and print it out to standard error stream. This will allow you to see the exception type and do your `try` block accordingly.