# Throwing Exceptions Correctly

Tags: c#, exception

I have the following code

```
    public HttpResponseMessage AddDataToDatabase([FromBody] Data data)
    {
        try
        {
            var token = _tokenService.GetToken(Request.Headers.Authorization);

            if (_pService.Permission(_tokenService.GetUserId(token), "Enable_Data"))
            {
                _noteService.AddData(data, _tokenService.GetUserId(token));
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Data has been added to the case.");
            }

            throw new HttpResponseException(
                Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Cannot add data because you don't have permission."));

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            if (exception is SqlException)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(
                    Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable, exception));
            }

            if (exception is ArgumentException)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(
                    Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, exception.Message));
            }

            throw;
        }
    }
```

I want to catch the Forbidden Exception like other exception in the catch block but not sure how to do that. The way I am returning Forbidden exception right now breaks unit tests which return SqlException and ArgumentExpception.

How can I throw exceptions correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to catch the exception for "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661780/how-to-catch-the-exception-for-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-403-forbi)

Answer (score 0):

By far, the easiest way is to simply do it like this.

```
catch (Exception exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

Unlike your code, this code also handles unanticipated exceptions instead of just `SqlException` and `ArgumentException`.

But why are you doing this? If you want the exception to propagate out to the caller, then simply remove the `try...catch` block in this method. Then just throw the desired exception in your code.

If you are capturing and converting third-party exceptions, the recommended approach is as follows.

```
catch (SqlException exception)
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(
        Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable, exception));
}
catch (ArgumentException exception)
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(
        Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, exception.Message));
}
```

Comment: I am using Moq to moq the controllers and the way its setup right now is that it catches specific exceptions and throws it to the users. Can the method above solve that?

Comment: What does *throws it to the users* mean? If you want the exception to propagate to the caller, then don't catch them (i.e. don't use `try...catch`).

Comment: It sends the response back, Eg if its a sql Expception I am Asserting the following way 
`Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable, ex.Response.StatusCode);`. The status code returned here is SqlException

Answer (score 0):

you should probably replace your `if` logic in your catch by using more selective catch :

```
    catch (SqlException exception)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(
            Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable, exception));
    }
    catch (ArgumentException exception) 
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(
            Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, exception.Message));
    }
```

The uncaught exceptions will  simplypass through (as when you you use `throw;`).

If you want to catch another type of exception, just add it to the list.

However, it is not very clear how your tests are broken. You should provide more details at this level if you want more help.