# Is there a way to extract the message from WebException?

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse

Is there a way to extract the text that is being sent back as part of the WebException that occurs can occur with a HttpWebResponse?  I can get all of the header information but there is a custom message being returned with the 400 or 401 response that I would like to get if possible.  I am currently handling the exception in my test like this:

```
        var ex = Assert.Throws<WebException>(() =>
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = Utils.GetRawResponse(url);
        });

        Assert.Contains("401", ex.Message);
```

Here is how am getting the response:

```
public static HttpWebResponse GetRawResponse(string requestURL)
{

    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestURL) as HttpWebRequest;

    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;


    return response;

}
```

And this works, but does not have the custom message.

Top hopefully be a little more clear am am referring to the message text in the bottom of the screenshot.:
  [image]

Comment: That message should be in the response body, have you tried to get the response stream and read it to a string?

Comment: Ah stream the exception response... duh.

Comment: In the end, a 400 response is a normal web response, inside a WebException there is a Response object with the real response from the server

Comment: Yup I saw that and just didn't even think about getting the response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HttpWebResponse returns 404 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857512/httpwebresponse-returns-404-error)

Comment: @AdamMaras - this is not a precise duplicate.  Related perhaps.  I was asking how to get the message out of the exception response, not how to handle the exception.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Gusmans reminder I created a method to extract the response from the WebException:

```
    public static string ParseExceptionRespose(WebException exception)
    {
        string responseContents;
        Stream descrption = ((HttpWebResponse)exception.Response).GetResponseStream();

        using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(descrption))
        {
            responseContents = readStream.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return responseContents;

    }
```

Comment: Lifesaver! this was surprisingly difficult to obtain via the vanilla class!

Answer (score 1):

When handling the exception, try something like:

```
if (ex.Response.ContentLength > 0) 
{
    string ResponseBody = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    // Do whatever you want with ResponseBody
}
```

Similar to examples in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.contentlength(v=vs.110).aspx)

The key point being that WebException had a Response property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response(v=vs.110).aspx